# LogonUser: The program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: c++, winapi

The following use of `LogonUser` will crash my application.

```
inline std::string w_to_string(std::wstring wstr) {
    typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_type;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;
    return converter.to_bytes(wstr);
}

inline const std::wstring to_wstring(const std::string& str) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    return converter.from_bytes(str);
}

inline bool verify(const std::string username,
        const std::string password, const std::string domain) {
    auto user = to_wstring(username);
    auto pass = to_wstring(password);
    auto dom  = to_wstring(domain);
    PHANDLE hToken;
    //UNICODE is set
    return LogonUser(user.c_str(), dom.c_str(), pass.c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, hToken);
}
```

However if I replace `auto pass = to_wstring(password);` with `auto pass = to_wstring("test");` everything works fine.

Can someone explain why this is the case and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your strings, it is with your `hToken` variable.  You are passing an uninitialized pointer to `LogonUser()`, so it writes the user's token to random memory, which is undefined behavior so anything can happen.

You need to pass a pointer to a valid `HANDLE` variable, and then call `CloseHandle()` when you are done using it, eg:

```
inline bool verify(const std::string username, const std::string password, const std::string domain)
{
    auto user = to_wstring(username);
    auto pass = to_wstring(password);
    auto dom  = to_wstring(domain);
    HANDLE hToken;
    bool success = LogonUserW(user.c_str(), dom.c_str(), pass.c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken);
    if (success)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    return success;
}
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```
inline bool verify(const std::string username, const std::string password, const std::string domain)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    bool success = LogonUserW(to_wstring(username).c_str(), to_wstring(domain).c_str(), to_wstring(password).c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken);
    if (success)
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    return success;
}
```